# Scala reference equality

Tags: scala

How do you test reference equality in Scala?

```
val x = new Obj
val y = x
x.referenceEquals(y) // evaluates to true
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `eq`, which is a member of [AnyRef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/AnyRef.html):

```
val x = new Obj
val y = x
x eq y // evaluates to true
x ne y // evaluates to false
```

Comment: Thank you! For the record, this is documented here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/AnyRef.html

Comment: And its inverse is `ne`. You'll most likely want to use it in infix notation. Note that `eq`, `ne`, `==`, and `!=` don't throw a `NullPointerException` when the target object is null, even if it may look like it could (especially in non-infix notation).

Comment: @Jean: If I added the line "val z = null" (very bad Scala form) to the above, are you saying that z.eq(x) will not throw an exception even though z is null? I was so skeptical of this, I went to http://www.simplyscala.com/ (online access to REPL) and tried it out interactively. And you're correct. That's wonderful and certainly better than Java's throwing an NPE. Tyvm for the clarification.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium Exactly. Looks like those “methods” benefit from a little compiler magic. :-)